# join in codeigniter returns multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a problem joining two tables. In my first table, I want to retrieve 1 row for the time, and in the 2nd table I want to retrieve the table_number and table_sizes with both table having the same key which is the resto_id. But it seems to return repeating values for the time. I've tried using group_by but it didnt work out.

here's my model:

```
$this->db->where('resto_settings_time.resto_id',$id);
$this->db->select('op_time_start,op_time_end, table_number, table_size');
$this->db->from('resto_settings_time');
$this->db->join('resto_settings_table', 'resto_settings_time.resto_id = resto_settings_table.resto_id', 'left');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

my Controller:

```
$data['rows'] = $this->process_resto_list->rsrv_details($id);
    $this->load->view('sample',$data);
```

my view:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo $start= $row->op_time_start . br();
        echo $end= $row->op_time_end . br();
        echo $num = $row->table_number . br();
        echo $size = $row->table_size . br();
    }
```

And here is what it returns:

> 07:00:00
>   24:00:00
>   7
>   3
>   07:00:00
>   24:00:00
>   6
>   4

I would like 07:00:00 24:00:00 to repeat only once.. Please help me out, I'm really confused. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: please post structures of tables with some sample data

Answer (score 0):

i did not get your problem but for removing duplicate data you have to use group by query

```
$this->db->group_by()
```

Comment: i tried using group_by() but it only returns 07:00:00 24:00:00 7 3 without the 6 4. I'd like to only display one  07:00:00 24:00:00 (which is the time) and the table_numbers 7 3 6 4

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for your help. I solved my problem, I did not use join, instead, I called my model twice in my controller and placed the values in array. That solved my problem.